# Adding String url's of images from storage to firestore doesn't work

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

Adding photos urls to the firestore wasn't gone perfectly for me

users have to add pictures to my application.now when the user click save button These pictures must be saved in the firebase storage and their urls in the firestore .when I used the code below :

```
for ( i = 0; i < totalItemSelected; i++) {

     StorageReference storage=mStorage
         .child("User_Pictures")
         .child(UID)
         .child("Ads_pictures")
         .child(MyAds.getId())

   .child(System.currentTimeMillis()+"."+getFileExtension(fileUri));

     storage.putFile(fileUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
          @Override
          public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
          Toast.makeText(getContext(), "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          newUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
          assert newUri != null;
          Adphotos_item adphotos_item=new Adphotos_item(newUri.toString());
          // Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
          // map.put("listExample", Arrays.asList(newUri.toString()));
          Ref.collection("Users")
              .document(UID)
              .collection("MyAds")
              .document(MyAds.getId())
              .collection("photos")
              .document()
           .set(adphotos_item,SetOptions.merge());
          }
     });

}
```

I expected that by looping it will add both  images in the storage and looping to add urls in the firestore **BUT** ,the results was  photos in the firebase storage was added successfully but the part of adding urls to the firestore wasn't done. it gives an error in the database.'*Error loading collections*'.
[image]

---

How can I make he urls appear in   firestore , what should I change in my code?

Comment: Please add the entire error that you get and please indicate at which line of code does it occur.

Comment: hi , I edited my post including error message. note that photos added successfully in the storage but what I got in the firesore is like that . also no errors on android phone

Comment: I think this question would be better suited for [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/).

Comment: thanks Alex, well I will email them, but do you have a method for what I want and I think it will be useful for all  not me . I follow your videos So if you have a tutorial for the issues I want I will be grateful

Comment: Not yet but hope I'll find some time to do it. Thanks for watching my videos!